# Null Values Exception handling in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

ex:1

```
result='1,2';
long[] ItemsToSkip = result.Split(',').Select(x => long.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

I have one array its working for non null vales correctly.ex1
ex:2

```
result='';
long[] ItemsToSkip = result.Split(',').Select(x => long.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

for ex2:for null values i am getting error **System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'**

can please someone explain how to handled this in linq

Comment: That duplicate is for `int` but it's exactly the same code.

Comment: Provide a [mre]; your code doesn't compile and when fixed, the second code block returns an empty array. Do you mean `var result = ","`? See duplicate, see also `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: I don't see any `Null Values` here.. The problem is, an empty string isn't a valid integer.